# Java/Kotlin: Finding the intersection of multiple HashSets by class ID

Tags: java, kotlin, set, guava, hashset

I'm having trouble finding the intersection of an Array of Hashed Sets that contain a data Class (where I want to intersect by identifier):

```
class Protein(val id: String, val score: Double, val molw: Double, val spc: Int)
```

I've pulled in some data from a .csv file into this type of structure:

```
ArrayList<HashSet<Protein>>
```

So I have six array lists [1 for each csv], each containing one hashed set that contains thousands of Protein structures. Here's what I've tried so far to get an intersection HashSet based off of common Protein.id:

```
fun intersection(data: ArrayList<HashSet<Protein>>): HashSet<Protein> {

val intersectionSet = HashSet<Protein>(data[0])

for (i in 1..data.size) {
    intersectionSet.retainAll(data[i])
}
return intersectionSet
}
```

This returns an empty list, which makes sense given that it's trying to intersect Protein objects and match each criteria as a whole.

How do I call data[i].id as my intersection criteria? I'm fairly new to Kotlin and data classes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add definitions for the `hashCode` and `equals` function in the `Protein` class as follows, then the `HashSet` will be able to appropriately check the intersection using the `id` field.

```
class Protein(val id: String, val score: Double, val molw: Double, val spc: Int) {
  override fun hashCode() = id.hashCode()
  override fun equals(other: Any?) = other?.let { id == (it as Protein).id } ?: false
}
```

Also you probably want to change the range in your loop within the `intersection` function to be `1..(data.size-1)` instead of `1..data.size` to avoid going out of bounds. Alternatively you could write it functionally as follows:

```
fun intersection(data: ArrayList<HashSet<Protein>>): HashSet<Protein> {
  return data.reduce { acc, it -> acc.apply { retainAll(it) } }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution; works like a charm for both my version of the intersection function and for what you provided. Also good catch with the 1..data.size call. Follow up Q - is there any reason why the hashCode() override needs to be specified as an Int? When I run the code without specifying a type, it works the same.

Comment: You're right. There is no reason to specify the type since the function body is just an expression and the compiler can infer the type. Same goes for the `equals`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

To simplify the given answer, you can use `apply`:

```
return data.reduce { acc, it -> acc.apply { retainAll(it) } }
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed that. I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you dont want to be dependent on the input to be a Hashset, you can do the following:

```
fun <T> multiIntersect(data: Collection<Set<T>>) = 
    HashSet(data.minBy { it.size }!!).apply {  data.forEach { retainAll(it) } }
```

By starting off with the smallest set, you can potentially save a lot of runtime, because retrieving the size of a set can be done in constant time, as its saved in a field of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some inbuilt function of kotlin

```
infix fun <T> Array<out T>.intersect(
    other: Iterable<T>
): Set<T> (source)

infix fun ByteArray.intersect(
    other: Iterable<Byte>
): Set<Byte> (source)

infix fun ShortArray.intersect(
    other: Iterable<Short>
): Set<Short> (source)

infix fun IntArray.intersect(other: Iterable<Int>): Set<Int>
(source)
infix fun LongArray.intersect(
    other: Iterable<Long>
): Set<Long>(source)

infix fun FloatArray.intersect(
    other: Iterable<Float>
): Set<Float> (source)

infix fun DoubleArray.intersect(
    other: Iterable<Double>
): Set<Double> (source)

infix fun BooleanArray.intersect(
    other: Iterable<Boolean>
): Set<Boolean> (source)

infix fun CharArray.intersect(
    other: Iterable<Char>
): Set<Char> (source)
```

Returns a set containing all elements that are contained by both this array and the specified collection.

The returned set preserves the element iteration order of the original array.