# Kotlin ArrayList<HashSet<data class>> .reduce function not working with subset of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, kotlin, hashset, reduce

I have a data class like this:

```
data class Protein(val id: String, val score: Double, val molw: Double, val spc: Int) {
    override fun hashCode() = id.hashCode()
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = other?.let { id == (it as Protein).id } ?: false
}
```

[As per another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891344/java-kotlin-finding-the-intersection-of-multiple-hashsets-by-class-id), I now have a function that can reduce an ArrayList of HashSets with Proteins

```
fun intersection(data: ArrayList<HashSet<Protein>>): HashSet<Protein> {
  return data.reduce { acc, it -> acc.retainAll(it); acc }
}
```

What I want to do is take a subset of the original ArrayList and return a reduced version. So I tried to do this:

```
fun intersection(data: ArrayList<HashSet<Protein>>, combination: List<Int>): HashSet<Protein> {
val newdata = ArrayList<HashSet<Protein>>()
for (entry in combination) {
    newdata.add(data[entry-1]) }
return newdata.reduce { acc, it -> acc.retainAll(it); acc } }
```

Combination tells the function which entries to take from the data ArrayList (eg 1,2,4). The size of the newdata ArrayList will always be 3 (checked this too).

When I run the raw data (ArrayList of 6) through the first intersection function, it reduces just fine. When I run the same data through the second function, it returns a map error, saying that the Key is not found.

I have a feeling this has something to do with the override function for the Protein data class, but I can't find anything about how to work with functional programming for reduce...

Comment: can you provide the code you invoke the intersection method with?

Comment: I call the intersection function from within another function call, but I pass in two arguments: an ArrayList of HashSets of Proteins, and an Array List of Lists. I think this is what you asked for?

Comment: spcSum(intersection(controlIDList, permutations[i-1]), controlIDList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified the code a bit and got the following:

```
fun intersection(data: List<HashSet<Protein>>) =
    data.reduce { acc, it -> acc.apply { retainAll(it) } }

fun intersection(data: List<HashSet<Protein>>, combination: List<Int>) =
    intersection(combination.map { data[it - 1] })
```

I was able to get the expected result with:

```
val s1 = hashSetOf(Protein("1",2.0, 2.0,1), Protein("2",2.0, 2.0,1))
val s2 = hashSetOf(Protein("3",2.0, 2.0,1), Protein("2",2.0, 2.0,1))
val s3 = hashSetOf(Protein("3",2.0, 2.0,1), Protein("4",2.0, 2.0,1))
println(intersection(listOf(s1,s2,s3), listOf(1,2))) //[Protein(id=2, score=2.0, molw=2.0, spc=1)]
```

So no error occurred. Can you please provide your test code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far. 2 questions. Are both intersection functions in your answer supposed to have the same name? And does your answer work with ArrayLists or just Lists? Cheers :)

Comment: 1. These are overloads, they are distinguished by their parameter list, this is fine
2. You should prefer interfaces (`List`) to concrete classes whenever possible. Yes, `ArrayList` is a `List` and can be passed as an argument

Comment: Cheers for the help. You are correct - no error occurred. The problem I was having was downstream in another call (the spcSum).